# Which approach is better to calculate the length of an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

What is the difference between `len(list(iterator))` and `sum(1 for _ in iterator)`?
Subsequently, which is the best one to use to calculate the length of an iterator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one uses O(n) space, because it has to build list. The second one uses O(1) space, because it doesn't have to remember an element once the running total has been updated.

Neither one is terribly useful, as you've discarded every element from the original iterator without looking at any of them. You are left with how long the iterator *was*. Assuming you are OK with that, O(1) space is better than O(n).

Answer (score 1):

While I can't argue with chepner's logic, a quick benchmark seems to produce the opposite conclusion, at least in terms of time.

```
import time

def option1(a):
    return len(list(a))

def option2(b):
    return sum(1 for _ in b)

start = time.time()
for i in range(20000):
    a0 = range(1, 10000)
    a = option1(map(lambda x: x + 1, a0))
end = time.time()
print("Option 1:", end - start, "seconds")

start = time.time()
for i in range(20000):
    a0 = range(1, 10000)
    a = option2(map(lambda x: x + 1, a0))
end = time.time()
print("Option 2:", end - start, "seconds")
```

Output:

```
Option 1: 14.580924987792969 seconds
Option 2: 19.70468544960022 seconds
```

So, at least in terms of time, the second option is 35% slower (as I increase the length of the iterables, the first option does seem to scale slightly worse, but not by much). It's also worth noting that the straight imperative solution with no generators and no intermediate lists, i.e.

```
def option3(c):
    i = 0
    for _ in c:
        i += 1
    return i
```

performs only slightly better than Option 2, giving 18.61347 seconds on the same inputs as in the above code.

So in summary, it seems that forcing the list is actually somewhat faster, provided you have the space to produce the intermediate list. I tested it with iterables up to 50,000 elements, and it still outperformed the generator-based solution.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the benchmark. 
I think a stateless solution (first one) is wiser for my context (tons of tiny files & the counting is done by a distributed scheduler (airflow))

Comment: How can we explain that the first solution performs better in terms of execution time?

Comment: I honestly don't have a good theory. Originally, I thought it was the generator expression adding complexity, since it's basically a bunch of implicit `yield` statements that would add some overhead. But then that doesn't explain why Option 3 performs similarly to Option 2, when it has no generators, no recursion, and no intermediate data structures (honestly, my guess before running these tests would've been that Option 3 would blow the others out of the water). Perhaps someone with a bit more understanding of the internals of Python might be able to explain it.